# amCharts Postprocessing to retrieve data for graph

Tags: javascript, json, amcharts

I am trying to use amcharts to display some data from my server. However, the API format does not seem compatible with amCharts directly. I believe I would need to use the postProcess function to manage the data first. But am at a loss due to the lack of error messages and my inexperience in javascript.

Following their guide, this is where I have gotten:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "$CHART$", {
  "type": "serial",
  "legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 10,
    "maxColumns": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10
  },
"dataLoader": {
    "format": "json",
    "postProcess": function( data, config, chart ) {
    var newData = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++ ) {
      var dataPoint = {};
      dataPoint= data["items"];
      
      newData.push( dataPoint );
    }
    return newData;
  },
    "showCurtain": true,
    "showErrors": true,
    "url": "*url*",
    "headers": [{
    "key": "Accept",
    "value": "application/javascript, application/json",
    "Authorization":"Basic *encodedpassword*"
  }]
    
  },  "categoryField": "timestamp",
  "graphs": [  {
    "valueField": "value",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderColor": "#6698FF",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "bulletAlpha":0,
    "bulletSize":0,
    "title":"ServerData",
    "lineThickness": 2,
    "lineColor": "#6698FF",
    "lineAlpha": 0.5,
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "fillColors":"#6698FF",
  } ],
  "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "dashLength": 5,
        "gridCount": 10,
        "position": "left",
     "unit": "V",
    }],
  "categoryAxis": {
    "minPeriod": "mm",
    "labelsEnabled": false
  },
  "chartCursor": {
    "oneBalloonOnly": true,
    "zoomable":true
  },
} );
```

The sample output from the API of the server is as follows:

```
{"href":"*url/value*","offset":0,"limit":20,"items":[
{"stateVarId":"value1","timestamp":1523939135978,"value":887.0},
{"stateVarId":"value1","timestamp":1523935535977,"value":887.0},{"stateVarId":"value1","timestamp":1523845535955,"value":887.0}]}
```

In order to allow amCharts to use the values, it should not be inside the "items":[ ...] portion.

As such the postProcess function should look inside the JSON format and return the contents of "items".

If further information is needed, do let me know. I will try to fill in any missing details.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your postProcess method isn't pushing the array of items correctly as you're creating an array of arrays, rather than a flattened array. Here's what's happening in your loop for each row of your data:

```
  var dataPoint = {};
  dataPoint= data["items"]; //dataPoint is now an array

  //this pushses the array as an element of newData, resulting in
  //[ [/*first items array*], [/*second items array*], ...]
  newData.push( dataPoint );
```

What you want instead is to loop through the `data["items"]` array and push each element individually into your newData array, or use [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to do that for you:

```
  //concatenates the existing newData array
  //with the next data["items"] array
  newData = newData.concat(data["items"]);
```

Side note - date/timestamp-based data needs to be in [ascending order if you're using `parseDates`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#parseDates), which is missing in your config (`minPeriod` won't work without it). Your sample API response has your items sorted in descending timestamp order, so make sure you sort newData prior to returning it in postProcess.

Answer (score 0):

Had a discussion with amCharts, this is the official answer:

```
"postProcess": function( data, config, chart ) {
var newData = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++ ) {
  var dataPoint = {};
  dataPoint= data.items[i];
  newData.push( dataPoint );
}
return newData;
},
```

The real reason why it wasn't working for me though, is due to CORS error in my website.

Thanks to whoever viewed my question for your time. =D